# javascript / ajax querying

Tags: javascript, ajax

I currently have a web page that uses javascript, however; when I use my Ajax to move towards the DB my responseText is always empty.

js to make the flag and send query

```
 objAjaxUpdates.main_flag = "getNames";
    objAjaxUpdates.SendQuery(query);
```

next in the flow
(The url is an aspx file)

```
this.SendQuery = function(data) {
        this.Initialize();
        if (this.req != null) {
            //alert(data);
            //alert(this.url + " " + this.main_flag);
            this.req.open("POST", this.url);
            this.req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            this.req.onreadystatechange = this.processData;
            this.req.send(data);
        }
    }
```

Next

```
this.processData = function() {
        if (objAjaxUpdates.req.readyState == 4) {
            if (objAjaxUpdates.req.status == 200) {
                if (objAjaxUpdates.req.responseText == "") {


                    alert('No Return');
                }
                else { 
                   ...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using Chrome or FireFox's javascript debugger to step through the code? You need to make sure it's sending what you think it is.

Comment: I'm only allowed to use IE or Safari. While stepping throught it with VS2008, everything appears to be working just fine, it's just when it checks for the readystate and status I notice the response header is "", thus moving to the alert('No Return'). There are other functions that are present that do not have this problem and I am just stumped as to why this function does.

Comment: Are you seeing the "No Return" alert?  (If so, that means you are successfully reaching the server, and it is sending back an empty response with a `200 OK` message.  In that case, the error is on your server.)

Comment: Could I be referencing something wrong? Yes, I get no Return everytime.

Comment: Have you added debug statements on the server to see what it is doing?

Comment: after the sendQuery function, the code should go to the aspx.cs file, however; it does not. It goes to the next part as indicated. I have the appropriate case names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the library you are using. But the procedure looks correct to me. (There are libraries like jQuery which avoids you to work on the low-level AJAX API, checking response code and so on.)

I advise you to work with something like Firebug for Mozilla, or the Chrome Developer Tools to "debug" your AJAX machinery.

There still is that good old technique:

- First test the requests to the server manually.
- Then, do a dumb AJAX request.
- At the end, test both components.

Comment: I"m only allowed to use IE or Safari. I'm new to this so how would I go about doing the first two tests?

Comment: If your webpage is available publicly on the Internet, it is very important that you check it works on Chrome and Firefox, because they're more used than IE and Safari.

A rule of thumb is that if it works on either Firefox, or Chrome, or Safari, it should work on the other two as well.

Nothing prevents you to use Firefox tools even if the website is meant to be viewed on IE only.

Try to split your code in small pieces and test these pieces on each browser.